# R time_to_event function gives an error

Tags: raster, r, time-series

I am using the [`time_to_event`](https://rdrr.io/cran/spatialEco/man/time_to_event.html) function (spatialEco) on a raster time series.

The function works when I run the example in the vignette, but when I apply it to my dataset I got this error.

> Error in if (x[1](https://rdrr.io/cran/spatialEco/man/time_to_event.html) == y) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I have removed some NA values but same problems.

My code is the following (`s1_max` is the rasterstack dataset with values 0 and 1):

```
t2e <- function(x) { time_to_event(x, y=1, dir = "LR", int = F, up.to = F) }
( k <- calc(s1_max, fun=time_to_event) )
```

Please can anybody help to understand the error?

Comment: What's `s1_max`? Can you outline its class, shape and contents - like is it a raster or a stack and what are the typical values in it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some details on your data. Is it a stack, how many layers, what are the values of the rasters, etc... I used this function recently with no issues but, it could be something to do with you data that has uncovered a bug or a change in the raster package that is causing unexpected behavior.

Comment: The only way I have been able to recreate this specific error is when NA is the first value in the vector. There can be other NA's in the vector and it runs fine. I will add a way to hand this in the function but, I suspect that you have not fixed your NA  problem.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, many thanks. 

this is my stack (original is bigger):
> s1_max
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 150, 198, 29700, 18  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.05, 0.05  (x, y)
extent     : -92.45, -82.55, 10.5, 18  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : layer.1.1.1.1, layer.2.1.1.1,  ... 
min values :             0,             0,     ... 
max values :             1,             1,     ... 


here I remove the NA:
> s1_max[is.na(s1_max)] <- 0

here check NA: 
> table(is.na(s1_max[]))

 FALSE 
534600

Comment: Hi again Jeffrey, here is the dataset 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mXmwwDVhB-hv9EzgCl6zsVJLdMrH9Wzb/view?usp=sharing
This function would be very useful for my researches